# Not able to install Spark 2.0 in CDH 5.7.5

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to install SPARK 2.0 in my CDH 5.7.5 cluster. While doing that i am getting below error

```
CDH (lower than 5.12) parcel required for SPARK2 (2.0.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.113931) is not available
```

P.S: Followed [documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/spark2/latest/topics/spark2_installing.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Cloudera support, it is a bug in 5.7 and 5.8. This has been fixed in 5.9 and newer.

Adding to the @Ruslan answer, Who ever using CDH 5.7 and 5.8, they need to follow the below workaround

**under parcel configurations, uncheck `Validate Parcel Relations`**

Comment: You've just copied @Ruslan's answer and then selected yours as the right answer. That's pretty rude.

Comment: @BenWatson Check this conversation  http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Spark-2/m-p/48929/highlight/true

Answer (score 4):

uncheck Validate Parcel Relations in Parcel configuration

Comment: should it be checked again after successful Spark parcel activation?